# How to get Yardoc to output to STDOUT?

Tags: ruby, shell, yard

I've looked for templates that come with the gem (I can only find the default HTML outputter), I've searched the help and online docs for a switch that will redirect to STDOUT. I can't find anything on how I might approach this.

Is there an easy way to do this (perhaps a shell command?) or do I have wade through the source code?

Comment: Why do you need this kind of feature?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid writing the documentation to disk? Or are you trying to view the generated docs in the console?

Comment: @davogones I want to do both, because… @luacassus I'm writing a console app, and instead of duplicating documentation I could write the yardocs, and output certain tags when calling `help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create the following file as `test.rb`:

  ```
  # This class is cool
  class Test
    # This method is also cool
    def foo
    end
  end
  ```
- You *must* compile the yard documentation before you can output this. But you don't want the `doc` folder right? So let's omit that.

  ```
  yardoc --no-output test.rb
  ```

  This will only update the documentation inside `.yardoc` folder which is hidden. The `doc` folder will not be generated.
- Now you can see the documentation for specific objects in a few ways:

  ```
  > yard display "Test"
  # Outputs:
  ------------------------------------------ Class: Foo < Object

      This class is cool



  --------------------------------------------------------------

  > yard display "Test#foo"
  # Outputs:
  ------------------------------------------ Method: #meth (Foo)
                                            (Defined in: foo.rb)

      foo.meth -> Object
  --------------------------------------------------------------

      This method is cool
  ```

  This is the output that you get. You can get the yard documentation for any class/method using the `yard display` command.
- But hey, the output sucks! Let's create a template for it. Create the following `templates` folder with a few files:

  ```
  + your app
    + templates
      + default
        + class
        | + text
        |   + setup.rb
        |       def init
        |         super
        |         sections T('docstring')
        |       end
        + method
        | + text
        |   + setup.rb
        |       def init
        |         super
        |         sections T('docstring')
        |       end
        + method_details
        | + text
        |   + setup.rb
        |       def init
        |         super
        |         sections T('docstring')
        |       end
  ```

  All the `setup.rb` files must have the same content like `def init, super, sections T('docstring'), end`. This will make the `text` output display only the documentation, without any fancy headers and stuff.
- Now just run the same `yard display` command, but let's use our custom templates:

  ```
  > yard display Foo --template-path ./templates

  This class is cool

  > yard display "Foo#meth" --template-path ./templates

  This method is cool
  ```
- That's it. You *may* find that the `yard doc` may have too much of leading/trailing new lines in the output, you can use some other standard linux `head/tail` commands to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with this answer. I'm just finishing up something and then I'm out for a tech meet (I force myself to go outside every now and then:) so I won't get a chance to try this till tomorrow, but I'll let you know. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is really helpful answer, I didn't know about the `display` command at all. It'd be nice if the database was only in memory. I've actually started to hack on the library for a different reason so I'll see if I can make my own dreams come true! Thanks for this, much appreciated.